# Opensuse is checking media drive instead of internet

Tags: opensuse

I am little bit newbi for linux. I have used Ubuntu though, in that while installing package it directly search internet repository and fetch the application. But recently I have installed OpenSUSE, latest version with all update is running. But one thing I found very annoying that whenever I try to install something it search media / cd drive for package, when I say no then it will go and download it. Everytime I have to say no for media drives, isn't it possible to make it default? By default it search internet only.

Please let me know if any further details needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've completed your install, you can do all of your updates online (assuming bandwidth is not an issue. Go to YaST, the system administration tool. After typing in your admin password (which, like Ubuntu, may be the same as your user login password), go to Software Repositories.

You'll see a list of all the repositories that openSUSE currently uses to update your software. In the URL column, you'll see a line that starts "cd:///?devices=" with the Name column reading openSUSE-12.2-xxxx (depending on the build used on your DVD). Click on that line.

Look at the Properties below. Uncheck the Enabled box to keep YaST from checking the DVD altogether. If you still want to check the DVD for new software, but don't want it high on the priority list, change the Priority number higher (low numbers get higher priority) than the default 99.

You can also use Priority to pick your favorite online repositories by making their number lower.